# I am trying to extract sequences from a file, but getting following error

Tags: python

Code to extract sequences

```
from Bio import SeqIO
def get_cds_feature_with_qualifier_value(seq_record, name, value):
    for feature in genome_record.features:
        if feature.type == "CDS" and value in feature.qualifiers.get(name, []):
            return feature
    return None
  

genome_record = SeqIO.read("470.8208.gbk", "genbank")

db_xref = ['fig|470.8208.peg.2198', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2200', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2203', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2199', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2201', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2197', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2202', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2501', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2643', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2193', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2670', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2695', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2696', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2189', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2458', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2191', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2190', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2188', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2192', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2639', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3215', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2633', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2682', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3186', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2632', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2683', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3187', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2764', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2686', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2638', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2680', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2685', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2684', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2633', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2682', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3186', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2632', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2683', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3187', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2640', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3221', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3222', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3389', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2764', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2653', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3216', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3231', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2641', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2638', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2680', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2637', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2642', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2679', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3230', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2676', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2677', 'fig|470.8208.peg.1238', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2478', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2639', 'fig|470.8208.peg.854', 'fig|470.8208.peg.382', 'fig|470.8208.peg.383']

with open("nucleotides.fasta", "w") as nt_output, open("proteins.fasta", "w") as aa_output:
    for xref in db_xref:
        print ("Looking at " + xref)
        cds_feature = get_cds_feature_with_qualifier_value (genome_record, "db_xref", xref)
        gene_sequence = cds_feature.extract(genome_record.seq)
        protein_sequence = gene_sequence.translate(table=11, cds=True)
    
        # This is asking Python to halt if the translation does not match:
        assert protein_sequence == cds_feature.qualifiers["translation"][0]
 
        # Output FASTA records - note \n means insert a new line.
        # This is a little lazy as it won't line wrap the sequence:
        nt_output.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (xref, gene_sequence))
        aa_output.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (xref, gene_sequence))

print("Done")
```

getting following error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Bio/GenBank/Scanner.py:1394: BiopythonParserWarning: Truncated LOCUS line found - is this correct?
:'LOCUS       CP027704             3430798 bp    DNA     linear   UNK \n'
  BiopythonParserWarning,
Looking at fig|470.8208.peg.2198
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-323ff320990a> in <module>()
     15         print ("Looking at " + xref)
     16         cds_feature = get_cds_feature_with_qualifier_value (genome_record, "db_xref", xref)
---> 17         gene_sequence = cds_feature.extract(genome_record.seq)
     18         protein_sequence = gene_sequence.translate(table=11, cds=True)
     19 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between the `get_cds_feature_with_qualifier_value` call and its parameters `(genome_record, "db_xref", xref)`, so the call is probably failing, leaving cds_feature as `None`.

Generally, you should provide [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone else (who doesn't have the gbk file you're referencing) can still reproduce and troubleshoot your error.

Comment: Thank you, will take care next time. Removing space didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

'''
from Bio import SeqIO
def get_cds_feature_with_qualifier_value(seq_record, name, value):
for feature in genome_record.features:
if feature.type == "CDS" and value in feature.qualifiers.get(name, []):
return feature
return None

genome_record = SeqIO.read("470.8208.gbk", "genbank")

da_xref = ['fig|470.8208.peg.2198', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2200', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2203', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2199', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2201', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2197', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2202', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2501', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2643', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2193', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2670', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2695', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2696', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2189', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2458', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2191', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2190', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2188', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2192', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2639', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3215', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2633', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2682', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3186', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2632', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2683', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3187', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2764', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2686', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2638', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2680', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2685', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2684', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2633', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2682', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3186', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2632', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2683', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3187', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2640', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3221', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3222', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3389', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2764', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2653', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3216', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3231', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2641', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2638', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2680', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2637', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2642', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2679', 'fig|470.8208.peg.3230', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2676', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2677', 'fig|470.8208.peg.1238', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2478', 'fig|470.8208.peg.2639', 'fig|470.8208.peg.854', 'fig|470.8208.peg.382', 'fig|470.8208.peg.383']
db_xref=[]
for xref in da_xref:
db_xref.append('SEED:' + xref)

with open("nucleotides.fasta", "w") as nt_output, open("proteins.fasta", "w") as aa_output:
for xref in db_xref:
print ("Looking at", xref)
cds_feature = get_cds_feature_with_qualifier_value(genome_record, "db_xref", xref)
gene_sequence = cds_feature.extract(genome_record.seq)
protein_sequence = gene_sequence.translate(table=11, cds=True)

```
    # This is asking Python to halt if the translation does not match:
    assert protein_sequence == cds_feature.qualifiers["translation"][0]

    # Output FASTA records - note \n means insert a new line.
    # This is a little lazy as it won't line wrap the sequence:
    nt_output.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (xref, gene_sequence))
    aa_output.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (xref, gene_sequence))
```

print("Done")
'''